# Electron/React app freezing while using ps-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to simply check all the processes running on a system in an electron app with reactjs. I eventually want to do this on a loop every 10 seconds or so, but right now the app freezes up while I do the call to ps.lookup Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import VideoPlayer from  './components/Player';
import Library from './components/Library';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
const fs = remote.require('fs');
const ps = remote.require('ps-node')

class App extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
        recording : false,
         active : false,
        }
        this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
        let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            ps.lookup({command : 'Program x'}, function(err, resultList){
                if (err){
                    reject(err);
                } else{
                    resolve(resultList);
                }
            });
        });
        p.then( (data) => console.log(data));
    }
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>test</h1>

    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-process instead